# How to iterate through only specific column in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a 2d array like this:

```
arr = [0 3 1 0
       1 2 0 2
       0 0 2 0
       1 2 0 0]
```

My aim is don't iterate over a column once we find maximum number in it.

In the first iteration, max number is **3 in 2nd column**, *so don't go to second column in future iterations.*

Similarly in my 2nd iteration, max number is **2 in 4th column** *(Because we dont go to 2nd column anymore).*

This is what i tried:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
     //Input 2d array
     int arr[4][4];
     //Take the input
     for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
     {
      for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
        cin>>arr[i][j];
     }
     //Index array to store index of maximum number column
     int index[4] = {-1,-1,-1,-1}
     //Array to store max number in each row
     int max_arr[4] = {0,0,0,0};

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
     int max_num = -1;
     for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
      {
        if(j!=index[0] && j!=index[1] && j!=index[2] && j!=index[3])
         {
           if(max_num<arr[i][j])
            {
              max_num = arr[i][j];
              index[j] = j;
            }
         }
      }
      max_arr[i] = max_num;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: *My aim is don't iterate over a column once we find maximum number in it.* is either easy or hard, depending on how you think about it. Unless there is some order to the input, you HAVE to look at each element because there's no way to know if the next element will be bigger than the largest.

Comment: it's not your full code also not clear what is wrong with it? wrong output?

Comment: Yes. I'm getting wrong output. The `maximum number column` is also running even though i included the `if condition` in column iteration.

Comment: `for(int j=0; j<4; j++)` is iteration along row, `for(int i=0; i<4; i++)` is iteration along  column

Comment: Yeah i get it. I have included full code for your reference.

Comment: Then why you're looking for max value in row, not column? Or something was lost in translation?

Comment: index[ j ] = j; change this to index[ i ] = j;

Comment: @Friday I first I'll look for max value in a row. Then I'll see which column it belongs to. Then I want to eliminate that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to go about this is to simply evaluate the array by columns. This can be done with a little math. In your case, you use a 4x4 array. Start at index 0, add 4, add 4, add 4, then subtract 11 (bringing you to position 1). Add 4, add 4, add 4, subtract 11 (bringing you to position 2). Etc...

Here is the code I used, which works and is doable for *any* size array!

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t ARR_ROWS = 4;
    constexpr size_t ARR_COLS = 4;
    constexpr size_t ARR_SIZE = ARR_ROWS * ARR_COLS;

    int arr[ARR_SIZE] {
        0, 3, 1, 0,
        1, 2, 0, 2,
        0, 0, 2, 0,
        1, 2, 0, 0
    };

    // Store max values for columns
    int cols_max[ARR_COLS] { -1, -1, -1, -1 };

    // Start at index 0, then at 4 (3 times) to evaluate first
    // column. Next, subtract 11 from current index (12) to get
    // to index 1 (start of column 2). Add 4 (3 times) to
    // evaluate second column. Next, subtract 11 from current
    // index (13) to get to index 2 (start of column 3). Etc...
    size_t cur_index = 0;
    size_t cur_col = 0;
    const size_t subtract_to_start_next_col = ARR_SIZE - (ARR_COLS + 1);
    while (cur_index < ARR_SIZE)
    {
        // Max function for 'cols_max'
        if (cols_max[cur_col] < arr[cur_index])
            cols_max[cur_col] = arr[cur_index];

        if ( // When index is at the column's end (besides last value)
            (cur_index >= ARR_SIZE - ARR_COLS) && 
            (cur_index <= ARR_SIZE - 2)
        )
        {
            cur_index -= subtract_to_start_next_col;
            cur_col++;
        }
        else if (cur_index == ARR_SIZE - 1)
        { // When index is last value, add 1 to break loop
            cur_index++;
        }
        else
        { // Nothing special, just go to next value in column
            cur_index += ARR_COLS;
        }
    }

    // Print columns' max values (optional)...
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARR_COLS; ++i)
    {
        std::cout 
            << "Max for column " << (i + 1) << ": " << cols_max[i] 
            << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask if you have any questions!

Comment: There is likely a more concise way to do this math, but I leaned more towards verbose code and ample commenting instead of a complex solution to just save some lines.

Comment: Key word if you want to see more about the trick Drake's using here:  [Stride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_of_an_array)

Answer (score -1):

You need 3 loops, first for iterations, second for rows, third for columns. If you have found max at column let's say `0`, then you should blacklist that column and so on.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int m[ 4 ][ 4 ] = {  { 0, 3, 1, 0 } ,
                         { 1, 2, 0, 2 } ,
                         { 0, 0, 2, 0 } ,
                         { 1, 2, 0, 0 } };

    constexpr int max_number_of_itr { 4 };
    bool blacklisted[4] { false };

    for ( auto itr = 0; itr < max_number_of_itr; ++itr )
    {
        auto max { -1 };
        auto max_col_idx { -1 };

        for ( auto row = 0; row < 4; ++row )
        {
            for ( auto col = 0; col < 4; ++col )
            {
                if ( blacklisted[ col ] )
                    continue;

                auto val = m[ row ][ col ];
                if ( val > max )
                {
                    max = val;
                    max_col_idx = col;
                }
            }
        }

        blacklisted[ max_col_idx ] = true;

        std::cout << "max is " << max << " col " << max_col_idx << " ignored." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need 3 loops. Just one loop and some index math is needed :)

Comment: I don't like to obscure things. If there is no constraint about the problem I prefer to be readable. That's why i implemented this way.

Comment: Are you saying that math in code is unreadable? I feel that is a bad reason to make this evaluation (in the worst case) quadratic complexity when it could be linear. I mean no disrespect, but a double-nested for-loop seems more unreadable than adding 4 to an index counter. However, I'm sure some people would fully disagree with me. Ultimately, it's up to the author.

Comment: You are overthinking and yes im saying that index tricks are unreadable also  unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

```
index[ j ] = j;
```

change this to

```
index[ i ] = j;
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the asker's question, but it seems that this answer doesn't quite touch on what is being asked. I think the author is wanting a way to not iterate over a value more than once.

Comment: His code is ok It is already doing what he asking for. It just has a bug.